# Best way to import a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website where you guess the name of the picture. Do you guys have any ideas on how to import a list into my javascript or maybe HTML if that is better. This would be a list of picture files or links and an attribute like the name of the picture or what the picture represents. This would be the text the user has to match. I have functionality set up. Just having trouble with this list.

Comment: try to use JSON object.

Comment: there's no such thing as a JSON **object** @HarshPatel

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp @JaromandaX

Comment: @HarshPatel - using a w3schools link to prove your point? Do you see the irony?

Comment: @JaromandaX I do have a question tho, why does it seem like you don't like w3schools? Is it known to have inaccurate information?

Comment: I have nothing against w3schools, I simply don't trust anything that's written on that joke of a site. I use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) which both Chrome (google) and Microsoft have recently endorsed

Comment: When you open MDN and search JSON, On the very first line they used work like "JSON object" @JaromandaX

Comment: @HarshPatel If you read it *properly*, you'll see it refers to the window.JSON object, which has two (main) methods, `parse` and `stringify` \*eyeroll\*

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create one file ;

```
// pictureList.js

export default [
    { 'name' : '' , 'link' : '' , .... },
    { 'name' : '' , 'link' : '' , .... },
]
```

Then use it like :

```
import pictureList from 'path/to/pictureList.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON

```
myObj = [{ "imgName":"...", "imgUrl": "....."}, 
    { "imgName":"...", "imgUrl": "....."},
    { "imgName":"...", "imgUrl": "....."} ];

/* accessing first image name */
x = myObj[0].imgName;
```

Comment: Is there any way I could automate this or am i doomed to input them manually